# What does it mean that random variables of mean zero form a Hilbert space with the inner product being the covariance?

Tags: probability-theory

I see that the covariance can be interpreted as a measure of similarity like the dot product of two vectors, and that the correlation coefficient is akin to the cosine in the dot product, while the variance is the vector norm.

Indeed,

1. Symmetry: $\text{cov}(X, Y)=\text{cov}(Y, X)$
2. Bilinearity:  $\text{cov}(X, aY + bZ)=a\,\text{cov}(X, Y) + b \,\text{cov}(X, Z)$
3. Positive definitiveness: $ \text{cov}(X, X)=\text{var}(X)\geq 0$...

and it must only zero when the random variable is "zero."

But I am confused about the "mean zero" class equivalence part.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean zero requirement is to ensure the positive definiteness, i.e. if $X$ is in this space and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X)=0$ then $X$ is the zero random variable. (To have a unique "zero random variable" in this sense, you must first take the quotient by $X \sim Y$ if $X=Y$ a.s., which is the usual procedure used in defining the $L^p$ spaces.) If you bundle in all the random variables with finite variance, you don't have this property anymore because all constants will have $\operatorname{Cov}(c,c)=0$.

Comment: Right, I see that much, but how do random variables of mean zero come to form an equivalence class?

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate They don't, not really. However, you can achieve this construction by using the relation $X \sim Y$ if $X-Y$ is constant, and then each equivalence class can be represented by a mean zero random variable.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is when $X$ is the zero random variable, meaning that it is always constant $0,$ and when similar verbiage is meant to imply that *the mean* is zero.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate I don't understand, the distinction should be clear. For a random variable, being zero and having mean zero are entirely different things. Maybe you can give an example of a context that confused you.

Comment: I am trying to understand the explanation at [this precise point in this lecture](https://youtu.be/VudrNXCYJt4?t=2399).

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate That use of the word "class" is not meant to imply equivalence class. You just focus on only the zero mean random variables and identify random variables by $X \sim Y$ if $X=Y$ a.s., and then you have a Hilbert space.